# In Flex, How to access packaged file in apk?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, file, flash-builder

I am building an android app using FlashBuilder and is using a sqlite database, and the initial database shall be packaged into the apk (Android package). When the app runs firstly, the packaged database should be copied to "applicationDirectory".

However, problem comes.

I can use File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("xx.db") for the destination when using File.copyTo() function. However, how about the file to be copied (from the apk package)?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file with a FileStream, reading it into a ByteArray, and then writing that ByteArray to the final storage location with FileStream?

Comment: Actually the problem is that the packaged .db file is not found, but not the way of copying the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about the problem. Is it that you are getting an IOError when you try to copy a file(db) from the application directory to the app-storage directory? Have you checked the contents of the packaged apk? Why dont you consider creating the db in the app-storage directory when the application starts because that application directory is quite protective of its content.

What are you trying to achieve really?

P.S. Keep in mind that the Application directory is read only. So your code cannot write files that reside on that directory.